# Duplicate values in SharePoint Designer workflow while updating in column of 'External Data' type

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow

While trying to update list item in SharePoint Designer Workflow by getting value from an External Data, we see duplicates. How to remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you set values for 'External Data' type column?

If you set values for other type columns, do you see duplicates?

Comment: Getting data from 'External Data' type column to set up in List columns.